# SQL Recursive concatenation of a file and path name

Tags: sql, recursion, hierarchy

I just can't wrap my head around this...  I have 3 related tables in SQL Server:

**FileIds**

```
  Id
  FileName
```

**FolderIds**

```
  Id
  ParentId
  FolderName
```

**FileInfo**

```
  Id
  FolderId
  FileId
  FileAuthorId
  FileClientId
```

Sample data:

**FileIds**

```
  1, Gartner
  2, Parker
  3, Stepp
```

**FolderIds**

```
  1, null, Georgia
  2, 1, Atlanta
  3, 2, Terminus
  4, 3, Suite 1500
  5, 4, David Williams
  6, 4, Lisa Davidson
  7, 2, LaGrange
  8, 7, Dena Pressley
```

**FileInfo**

```
  1, 8, 1, null, null
  2, 5, 2, null, null
  3, 6, 3, null null
```

Sample output from view:

```
  Georgia.Atlanta.LaGrange.Dena Pressley:Gartner, null, null
  Georgia.Atlanta.Terminus.Suite 1500.David Williams:Parker, null, null
  Georgia.Atlanta.Terminus.Suite 1500.Lisa Davidson:Stepp, null, null
```

While this is not for a file directory, it is laid out like one (replace .'s and :'s with \'s) and I need to create a view that shows the full path...  It is easy to put the pieces together in code such as C#, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in SQL. I have looked up SQL Server's recursive CTE and I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should allow you to start using recursive CTE:

In here I'm only adding the folders, but you can do exactly the same, in another CTE to add the files

```
WITH folders (Id, ParentId, FolderName) 
AS (
    -- In here you select the first LEVEL
    SELECT Id, ParentId, FolderName FROM FolderIds
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    -- In here you join the previous LEVEL with new relative LEVELS
    SELECT b.Id, b.ParentId, a.FolderName CONCAT ' ' CONCAT b.FolderName
    FROM folders a 
        INNER JOIN FolderIds b 
            ON a.Id = b.ParentId
)
SELECT *
FROM folders
```